# Why do different homographies affect running time?

Tags: performance, opencv, matrix-multiplication, perspective, homography

I am applying OpenCV's `warpPerspective()` function to an image and I'm timing this task (only the call to the function, nothing else). I noticed that if I use different homographies the running time changes.

For example I tried using the identity matrix and found that it is faster than another homography that I generated with OpenCV's `findHomography()`, specifically this one:

```
[ -4.2374501377308356e+00, -4.1373817174321941e+00, 1.6044389922446646e+03,
  -1.6805996938549963e+00, -9.0838245171456080e+00, 1.9901208871396577e+03,
  -2.4454046226610403e-03, -8.2658343249518724e-03, 1.                     ]
```

Please note that the output is not my concern, I am only talking about running time. So why is it different?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm using OpenCV 3.4 on a PowerVR GX6650. I tested it with and without OpenCL and the pattern is still the same.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your measurements and reproduces this issue. Which version of OpenCV does this occur on, what platform?

Comment: the output image size is always the same? Might be because of caching during interpolation or in general the interpolation behaviour. In general warping iterates over the output image pixels, computes the covered input image positions and interpolates them. If many destination pixels do not hit the input image, there will be less interpolation involved, maybe.

Comment: Yes, the output image size stays the same. I think you might be right, it might have to do with how many times it needs to interpolate since it never needs to do that with the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Micka in the comments, the difference seems to be given by the different number of times that the interpolation method is called.